# Como exibir na view um arquivo JSON com chave/valor dinâmico?

Tags: javascript, json

Temos um arquivo JSON que nunca saberemos quantas chave/valor irá conter e preciso exibir na tela pra o usuário, como fazer isso uma vez que não tenho o nome da "chave" exemplo:

Na 1a. chamada ajax pode vir assim:

```
{
    "carros" : [
        {"fabricante":"fiat","modelo":"palio","ano":"2013","combustivel":"gasolina"},
        {"fabricante":"volkswagen","modelo":"fusca","ano":"1986","combustivel":"gasolina"},
        {"fabricante":"gm","modelo":"prisma","ano":"2011","combustivel":"gasolina"} 
    ]
}
```

Na 2a. chamada ajax pode vir assim:

```
{
    "carros" : [
        {"fabricante":"fiat","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"volkswagen","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"gm","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"ferrari","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"gm","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"fiat","teto_solar":"sim"}
    ]
}
```

Na 3a. chamada ajax pode vir assim:

```
{
    "carros" : [
        {"kit_multimidia":"sim","modelo":"palio","ano":"2013","combustivel":"gasolina"},
        {"kit_multimidia":"não","modelo":"fusca","ano":"1986","combustivel":"gasolina"}
    ]
}
```

Essa é a chamada Ajax: 
Notem que dentro do $.each como faço para exibir uma vez que desconheço o nome da "`Chave`" ?

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
             $.each(response.listaDeCarros, function (index, item) {
                console.log("Campo 1" + item.Campo1);
                console.log("Campo 2" + item.Campo2);
                console.log("Campo 3" + item.Campo3);
             });             
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo:

```js
response = {
    "carros" : [
        {"fabricante":"fiat","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"volkswagen","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"gm","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"ferrari","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"gm","teto_solar":"sim"},
        {"fabricante":"fiat","teto_solar":"sim"}
    ]
}

response.carros.forEach(carroItem => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(carroItem));
    Object.keys(carroItem).forEach((key, indice) => {
        console.log('indice: '+ indice +' - key: '+ key +' - Valor:'+ carroItem[key]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Leonardo seria mais interessante para o autor da pergunta e para outros usuários que descreve-se o que o código faz ao invés de só inserir o código na resposta.

Comment: Bom dia! @Leonardo Getulio obrigado pela colaboração, porém ficou ainda a dúvida de como pegar o `Valor` uma vez que tenho a `Chave` ?

Comment: Oi @hard123 fiz uma alteração no código, você pode acessar usando carroItem[key]

Comment: Ok! @Leonardo Getulio é isso mesmo que preciso !! vou adaptar as minhas necessidades ! Obrigado !!

Comment: @LeAndrade vou melhorar este quesito, sou novo aqui, estou aprendendo a responder e estou gostando muito de ajudar. Vou procurar ser o mais didático possível daqui em diante.